Hung Jury - time for a retrial
Imagine a person is charged with a felony but not a particularly serious felony. Perhaps the defendant is looking at doing a few months in prison. There is a trial and most but not all members of the jury feel the prosecution has proven the case beyond a reasonable doubt. As a result the judge has declared a mistrial.
Now the prosecution wants to try the defendant again. How long does it typically take for the second trial to start?
Now imagine during the first trial the prosecution introduction evidence that the defense thought was irrelevant. The judge thought the evidence was relevant and therefore it was allowed in. Between the time the first trial ended and the second trail started could the defense file an appeal to get the appellate court to asking them to not allowed the evidence in.

There are two parts to your question.

How long does it take to be tried again?

That will differ from state to state. All states have a time limit for a speedy trial. There is also a time limit to charge an offense. Both of these would have to be followed, as they were the first time. It is essentially like starting over.

Can something from the first trial be appealed?

An appeal would have to wait for a new trial. The second trial would be a new case.
